# Flashgun newborn photography

Tags: flash

I was wondering can I use a flash gun that goes on my camera  with studio continuous light kit for newborn and older kids? As unsure if safe?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a safety concern of any kind using flash guns around children or infants. I personally use a whole set of speedlights for virtually everything I shoot and don't use continuous lighting or studio strobes and I've never had an issue. If you're worried about infants being sensitive to strobes, that's also not an issue (maybe rare sufferers of photo-epilepsy might be an issue, but I've not heard of it happening personally, but that would be an issue for adults as well).

The one issue you might come up against is that the colour temperatures of your lights might not match. Does depend on what kind of continuous lighting you have. Speedlights are generally colour balanced at around daylight (so 5500K) whereas a lot of continuous lighting is much warmer (~3200K). Not always, a lot of LED panels use 5600k (but not all). You'd have to see what your continuous lighting is balanced to specifically as it is really very open ended in that department. If it is a problem, it can be easily fixed with gels.

Comment: Thank you my bulb lamps I think are 80w/125w. I have two of them. Its a start up kit. I thought point the flashgun to ceiling or wall to help. As I have trying natural lighting as I have a big patio window which I could use for home photos